# Instalador no puede encontrar el archivo ClrTypes.msi

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estaba probando la instalacion de mi aplicacion en otra maquina para probar que todo funciona correctamente, pero al momento de avanzar en la instalacion, cuando llega al paso 3 se detiene y me dice que un archivo fue cambiado de lugar y no lo puede encontrar, lo cual no tiene sentido porque obviamente no cambie nada de lugar. Inclusive genere varios instaladores probando sacar componentes para intentar llegar el problema, pero nada resulto (hace un dia que no doy con el problema). Cuando me dirijo a la carpeta donde se estaba generando los archivos del programa, me encuentro con que efectivamente se encuentra esa carpeta en cuestion vacia.
Adjunto una imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con otro archivo que se genera que es el manifiesto de implementacion clickonce mi aplicacion si se inicia, me permite modificar datos, etc (pero supongo que no esta instalada).
Lo unico que se me ocurre es conseguir ese arichivo uqe falta y colocarlo manualmente cuando se genere la carpeta

Comment: Probaste a quitar de los prerequisitos lo referente a SqlsysClrTypes?

Comment: Lo intete pero no los encontre, los buscare de vuelta (por si mire mal), ahora te comento si lo encuentro

Comment: Lo busque otra vez y lo pude encontrar, era eso, otro archivo que era localDB me generaba el error, pero no los queria desmarcar porque pense que eran paquetes que ayudaban en la conexion a la base de datos ¿puedes publicar tu cumentario asi te lo marco como respuesta?

Comment: Ahora deje como requisito previo el .NET framework, el crystal, y el SQLExpress (sin el localDB, que era otro archivo que me generaba error)

Comment: Si yo ya hice la instalacion previa de SQL, ¿es necesario indicarlo en los requisitros previos, o seria instalar lo que ya esta instalado? (ademas de que haria falta que este en otras maquinas es sql si es una maquina cliente).

Comment: Los requisitos previos son para comprobar (y en su defecto instalar) algo. Si ya lo has instalado, no es necesario.